# Call SQL Function for reach result row, and union returns

Tags: sql, function, union

Hi i have an sql function which returns a table (set of records)

```
SELECT * FROM myFunction('213123');
```

now i have a query which gives me all id's

```
SELECT "runnerId" FROM log GROUP BY "runnerId"
```

how can i make one query which calls the function for each "runnerId" and UNIONs all the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cross apply`/`outer apply` as  **ta.speot.is** said:

```
create function test_funct (@id int)
returns @retval table(id int not null primary key, data varchar(10)) 
as 
begin

 insert into @retval(id,data) values (@id,'test');
 return ;
end;


select  b.* from 

(
 select 1 as f1
 union
 select 2
)a
cross apply test_funct(a.f1) b -- or outer apply
```